# Варианты forward proxy

Tags: сервер, сеть, proxy, devops

Подскажите forward proxy, который умеет в задачи:

- уметь подставлять разные прокси для того, чтобы ходить с разных машин
- уметь давать управляющие команды прокси-серверу замену прокси
- к пердыдущему пункту. уметь в сессии или что-то подобное. Кажется, что это удобно было бы делать через хедеры.